# Can I use the audience targeting with FBA using Custom Provider?

Tags: forms-authentication, audience-targeting

Is there a way to use Custom Membership provider with Audience targetting?
The only way I found to do so is to duplicate the user creation by adding the user to Sharepoint group in addition to adding the user to the custom membership provider.
I think this is a big overhead, is there a better way to rely only on the custom membership provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a Role Provider too or use the SQL Role Provider and create FBA roles then add those roles to the SharePoint group.  Then have the FBA users added to the FBA role when created.